# Python Json to array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I want to put json into array.
I have 6 Json links (with the same size but different issues)

That was my try:

```
data=('0','0')
response = urllib.urlopen(URL)
data[0] = json.loads(response.read())
response = urllib.urlopen(URL)
data[1] = json.loads(response.read())
```

Do I have to initialize a 3d array?
Later it would be fine if I can work on the result like that:

```
result = data[0]['resu']['spc']
```

In the end i want to build a for loop which use dynamical the json links like that:

```
for w in range(0,len(URLs)):
    URLs[w]['resu']['spc']
```

Comment: `data` is a tuple which kannot be modified.

Comment: that means it is inpossible?

Comment: no - you have to use a list instead: it would work with `data=[0,0]` instead but see my answer for better solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (the current documentation does so, too) but you *can* do:

```
import json
import urllib2

urls=["http://example.com/json","https://example.com/json2"] # your urls here

data=[]
for u in urls:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(u)
    data.append(json.loads(response.read())) # while this normally works with Python 2, it is better to use data.append(json.loads(response.read().decode("utf8"))
```

for this you have to find out/guess the encoding of your response.

With requests it would be much simpler:

```
import requests

urls=["http://example.com/json","https://example.com/json2"] # your urls here
data=[requests.get(u).json() for u in urls]
```

Comment: i had the same idea, but isn´t bad for the performence to convert a json url in every loop ?

Comment: im not sure if i understand you correctly but (apart from using append instead of a list comprehension like in my second code sample) there is not much room for perfoemance improvements - if there are multiple urls then a loop is actually the only solution except for `map`

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable which makes them great for sharing between threads, but not so good for frequent changes.  Try using a list instead as they are designed for this very use case.  That being said, a dictionary can be nice as well:

```
import json
import urllib.request

data = {}
for url in urls:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        if response.status_code != 200: 
            continue // Handle errors here, I chose to continue
        // Remember that JSON must be in text format
        data[url] = json.loads(response.read().decode())
```

Just for giggles, here is a one liner:

```
// The lack of error checking in this is staggering though!
data = {u:json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(u).read().decode()) for u in urls}
```

Comment: ok that means i could build me a array with all my data for using them dynamical. that could be a solution. i´ll try

Comment: you cannot actually be sure which encoding to take for decode without checking the headers. just using default encoding with `.decode()` is propably not the best idea. utf-8 would be a better guess -> `.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: The default encoding is utf-8.